# How to update currentlocation and path between two points continuously?

Tags: android, android-maps

How to update currentlocation ping and path between 2 points continuosly as the location changes.

Comment: I am able to draw path and ping for particular latlog but dont know how should i update this ,is there anyone?

Comment: You may have got solution for this if yes then please post yours and here is a good example that may help you,http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Location/distancecalc/com.gebogebo.android.distancecalcfree.htm